# UIScrollView not Scrolling at all

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I've tried several s.o threads but none of them have solved this for me. I have a "containerScrollView" that won't let me scroll it. I've tried making it both longer and shorter than the contents of the view but that either doesn't work (longer) or turns the whole view white (shorter). On the iPhone 5 I can still only see down to the third label whereas I need to be able to scroll down past the "about" section. Suggestions? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYy1Q.jpg)

Comment: Have you set constraints for scroll view?

Comment: scrollview content size has to be more than your screen size then only you can scroll.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: 1430)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your scroll view has too much height in storyboard. Just make its height as same as the device height's.Then programmatically set the content size of scroll view. Either in

scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: (**whatever the height you need**))

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` is tricky when it comes to adding constraints. You should always add `UIView`to act as the content view of your `UIScrollView`. Your hierarchy should be something like this-

```
|---UIScrollView
    |---Content View
        |---UIImageView
        |---UILabel
        |---
```

Add a leading, top, trailing and bottom for your `UIScrollView` to your `superView`. Add a `UIView` as the content view with a leading, top, trailing and bottom. Also add equal width and equal height constraints from your content view **to the viewController view and not your `UIScrollView`**. Set the priority of the height constraint to be `250`. Now add all the subsequent views inside your content view happily! (Ensure your bottom most view has a bottom to the content view)

**Alternatively** based on your screenshot, you should use a `UITableView` if you are making something like a menu.